# VBA SQL loop using While and Wend

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've tried to write a loop that picks up the query condition from the cell, retrieves the value from the DB and when finished, it then picks up the next cells value and uses that as the new condition to query the DB and so on..

I get an error "Operation is not allowed when the object is open" with my following code. I am able to successfully query the first condition, but not able to move to the next.

[Q3] column has the criteria's

```
Set r = [Q3]
sSQL = "SELECT Key FROM TABLENAME WHERE Key = '" & r.Value & "'"
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Sheet1.Range("w3").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close

While r.Value > 0
Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Sheet1.Range("w3").CopyFromRecordset rs
Wend
```

Comment: The `rs.Open` should be outside your `While` loop.

Comment: @daShier That didn't work. It just queried the first cell and stopped. Would you be able to post a sample of what you are referring to as I may not have the syntax correct

Comment: It seems you are copying to the same cell `w3` each time through the loop, so I don't know what you are trying to do. Your code seems to have a logic error in the loop. We have no idea what `r` is or the end result you are looking for.

Comment: @marv, write for each loop for range of this criteria its easy since You already have working sample for 1st cell